# How to fix 'Image sent from Ios to android and is getting rotated 90cw in android but if i check exif information it shows orientation 0?

Tags: java, android, ios

This is my code to check if there is any exif data in a filepath and i am passing the file path i received from ios

```
int orientation=exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                angle = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                angle = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                angle = 270;
                break;
            default:
                angle = 0;
                break;
        }
        return angle;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: you should fix orientation of image before uploading, you might be loosing metadata of image while you are uploading.

Comment: when i open this image with exif data extractor app its coming properly  and showing orientation 90cw but in my app its always show 0 orientation

Comment: thats strange, in such case it should work.

Comment: yes but i don't know why there is no meta data when i am checking with exif interface in my app